# Finding the number of ways to fill three jobs with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Problem:

There are $3$ positions to be filled at a company. There are $7$ male applicants and
$6$ female applicants. An applicant can be selected for only one position. For the
first position, either a male for a female can be selected. For the second position,
a male must be selected. For the third position, a female must be selected. How many
different ways are there to select the applicants.

Answer:

Let $c$ be the count we are seeking. Let $c_1$ be the count of possible applicants
assuming we select a male for the first position. Let $c_2$ be the count of possible applicants assuming we select a female for the first position.
\begin{align*}
c &= c_1 + c_2 \\
c_1 &= 7(6)(6) = 252 \\
c_2 &= 6(7)(5) = 210 \\
c &= 252 + 210 \\
c &= 462
\end{align*}
Is my solution correct?

Comment: @JMoravitz If you put your comment as an answer, I will accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct, however it is far easier to fill position3 and position2 before considering who to use for position1.  You get $7\cdot 6\cdot 11 = 462$ far more quickly doing it that way.  This is a good example for emphasizing the fact that we get to decide the order in which we select things and we do not need to do the selection in the order the story dictates.